# Modification of Database Attribute

Tags: regex, database, postgresql, ip

I have my data stored in PostGre Open Source Database , the IP address is one column in the the database, i wish to run a query for example to modify the IP address from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.2` but the biggest problem is IP is stored with some data attached to it in a single column

So,

`192.168.1.1/RaghavIP` is to be modified to `192.168.1.2/RaghavIP`

I want the data to remain unchanged and only change the IP address

PostGRE supports regular expressions and substrings i have tried both but have no success

```
SELECT ipaddress
FROM mytable
WHERE ipaddress SIMILAR TO '%(_|__|___).(_|__|___).(_|__|___).(_|__|___)%';
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change *a specific IP address* to *another specific IP address*, without changing any trailing information, you can simply do:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET ipaddress = replace(ipaddress, '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2')
WHERE ipaddress LIKE '192.168.1.1%';
```

The `WHERE` clause is optional and will make the update faster on big tables.

If you want to update **only** Raghav's IP address, the query is even simpler:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET ipaddress = '192.168.1.2/RaghavIP'
WHERE ipaddress = '192.168.1.1/RaghavIP';
```

Comment: the first query is what exactly i was looking for thanks alot